# jQuery switching contaiers from links

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys im struggling to get this following to work, i have a set of 4 links which i need to display a div container for 3 and another for 1 and swicth back etc... any ideas?

```
<div class="content active">
 this is a main container
</div>

<div class="content news">
 this is a news container
</div>

<dl>
<dd><a href="">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="">link 1</a></dd>
<dd class="news"><a href="">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="">link 1</a></dd>
</dl>
```

need to show main container as default, when click on new DD item to swicth to the new container, but then if click on other dd links then switches back my js so far which is not working of course haha

```
$('dd a').bind('click',function(){
    if($('dd').hasClass('news')) {
        $('.content').removeClass('active');
        $('.content.news').addClass('active');
    } else if(!$('dd').hasClass('news')) {
        $('.content.news').removeClass('active');
        $('.content').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at using the `this` keyword to then be able to target the `parent()` `dd` of the clicked link e.g. `if($(this).parent('dd').hasClass('news')) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CSS to show the div w/ class "active"?

You could also replace `.removeClass('active')` with `.hide()` and `.addClass('active')` with `.show()`

Comment: Yes using CSS but i also tried show and hide just did not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need something like this

```
$('.news').css('display','none');

$('dd').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('news'))
{
$('.news').css('display','visible');    
}
}):
```

Comment: Tried that but seems to always show default and does not swicth :(

Comment: Can i know why you are using dd tag??

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be making this more complicated than necessary. This is one of those places where it might be easier to think about the problem. You want to show one container, show another on click, and then return using the other links.

This is an ideal job for IDs since they make it easier to identify one single box, but feel free to replace it with classes. Heres the HTML with IDs:

```
<div class="content active" id="default">
 this is a main container
</div>

<div class="content" id="news">
 this is a news container
</div>

<dl>
<dd><a href="javascript:show()">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="javascript:show()">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="javascript:show('news')">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="javascript:show()">link 1</a></dd>
</dl>
```

It also includes some javascript links, but you could just move this to the on click event in jQuery as well. I just find it clearer since we don't actually need to read data, we get it passed straight from the link. [Warning: some people don't like this but it can be useful].

Heres the javascript:

```
function show(id){
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    if($("#" + id).length)
        // in the if statement above you could even add && !$("#" + id).hasClass("active")
        // to default back to default if the current one is already active
        $("#" + id).addClass("active");
    else
        $("#default").addClass("active");
}
```

That worked for me. Note that I decided to show the default box if there is no id found, or if you add the hasClass(active) like I mention in the comment, to hide the box if it is currently active. You couple asely translate this into jQuery, but you would have to use a data- element to pass the ID, or include it in the href and prevent the default. I find this approach easier.

#### Edit: JQuery Solution

HTML with href replaced by the div reference (include the hash for safety and fallback).

```
<dl>
<dd><a href="#">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="#">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="#news">link 1</a></dd>
<dd><a href="#">link 1</a></dd>
</dl>
```

JQuery code to read the correct ID and display it:

```
$("dd a").click(function(event){
    // Prevent the link from going anywhere
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    // Get the link DIV from the href (this will fallback to scroll-page-to-div without JS)
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    if($(id).length)
        $(id).addClass("active");
    else
        $("#default").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I agree with what you say, dont know why did not think of the same thing.... long day however is it possible without having to use JS within teh HTML? thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah like I mentioned, with the only problem being passing the IDs. The simplicity of this solution is that you can expand it easely, using it to show anything. If you went to tie it in you'll either have to find a reference to the ID somewhere using the `.attr()` or `.prop()` on the link being clicked, or hardcode the ID's/classes to hide/display in the script. Just move everything inside the `show()` function into your on `.click(function)`; Also, you can use all of the above on a `dd` tag as well, and remove the a entirely. Or ignore it. As I said, expandable.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest and cleanest answer:

```
$('dd a').bind('click',function(){
    $('.content').hide();
    if($(this).parent('dd').hasClass('news')) {
        $('.content.news').show();
    } else {
        $('.content.active').show();
    }
});
```

You might want to rename the "active" class to something more descriptive.